# How to inject spring bean to CXFServlet extented class

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, cxf

I have a rest web service. In that at webservice start i have to start few other services. I decided to extend the `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet` class and in that initiate those services. So far i have extended the class and it's working now.

How can i inject spring bean to this extended class

my servlet

```
public class RestUIServlet extends CXFServlet {

   @Autowired
   private Util util; // Problem is to inject this.

   public RestUIServlet() {
        super();
       //TODO : Initialize service here
   }
}
```

My web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        test.RestUIServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My beans.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:spring/springContext.xml"/>
<context:property-placeholder/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PreferencesPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

<jaxrs:server id="services" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="uiServiceImpl"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="uiServiceImpl" class="test.UIServiceImpl"/>
```

I'm using cxf 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

you try following two steps.

1. add `<context:component-scan base-package="<package name>" />` in beans.xml this entry will scan/read all the stereo type annotations from the java classes from the mentioned package.
2. add `@Component` at class level.

I hope this will resolve problem.